# Why does Spark Streaming fail at String decoding due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I run a Spark Streaming (`createStream` API) application on a YARN cluster of 3 nodes with 128G RAM each (!) The app reads records from a Kafka topic and writes to HDFS.

Most of the time the application fails/is killed (mostly receiver fails) due to Java heap error no matter how much memory I configure to executor/driver.

```
16/11/23 13:00:20 WARN ReceiverTracker: Error reported by receiver for stream 0: Error handling message; exiting - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.lang.StringCoding$StringDecoder.decode(StringCoding.java:149)
        at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:193)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:426)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:491)
        at kafka.serializer.StringDecoder.fromBytes(Decoder.scala:50)
        at kafka.serializer.StringDecoder.fromBytes(Decoder.scala:42)
        at kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata.message(MessageAndMetadata.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaReceiver$MessageHandler.run(KafkaInputDStream.scala:137)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using KafkaUtil.createStream(....) single Receiver will be run in an spark executor and if the topic is partioned, multiple receiver threads run for each partition. So if your stream has large string objects and the frequency is high and all threads share single executor memory you may get OOM issue.

The below are the possible solutions.

1. As the job fails out of memory in receiver, First check the batch and block interval properties. If batch interval is grater(like 5 min) try with lesser value like(100ms).
2. Limit the rate of the records received per second as "spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate", also make ensure that
   "spark.streaming.unpersist" value is "true".
3. You may use KafkaUtil.KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String,
   StringDecoder, StringDecoder](streamingContext, kafkaParams,
   topics). In this case instead of single receiver spark executors
   directly connect to the kafka partition leads and receive the data
   parallel(each kfka partition is one KafkaRDD partition). Unlike
   multiple threads in single receiver executor  here multiple
   executors will run parallel and load will be distributed.

Comment: How do you make out we got OOM I driver or executor

Comment: from the log you have mentioned

Comment: 16/11/23 13:00:20 WARN ReceiverTracker: Error reported by receiver for stream 0: Error handling message; exiting - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Thanks my application is working by setting 'spark. streaming. receiver. maxRate', first I tried "spark. streaming. backpressure. enabled"="true" as this setting handles such situations dynamically but it didn't work do not know why.

Comment: @ Prudvi Sagar I have a few question around this we have some systems which sends high volume data to Kafka 24*7, In such cases, if my spark streaming app goes down for few hours or a day and once streaming application comes up how will spark behave?As per my knowledge with the help of checkpoint `createStreams/DirectAPI` it will read from the Kafka offset from where it left.Here I have doubt, How spark will process old messages and at what criteria spark will choose number of events/messages for the configured batch interval for old messages as messages count will enormous.

Comment: First I would like to give response on why   "spark. streaming. backpressure. enabled"="true" did not work for you, that is upper bounded by "spark. streaming. receiver. maxRate" so that is why the change  did not resolve you issue. We will face the same issue what you have faced now when enormous old messages need to be processed.

Comment: To enable backpressure what i need to do? I disable maxRate option before enabling backpressure but it was not working.

Comment: u r getting the out of memory issue might because of the you are receiver receiving very high freq string msg. If you set maXRate it limits  receiving frequency so that you are issue has resolved. The rate of receiving records will be dynamically set by the spark when you set "spark. streaming. backpressure. enabled"="true"(default value is false). If you want handle the situation with out setting "spark. streaming. receiver. maxRate"  and enabling the spark. streaming. backpressure. enabled"="true" it uses max receiver capacity. so still issue exist.

Comment: Hey I am sorry but I didn't understand this statement "If you want handle the situation with out setting "spark. streaming. receiver. maxRate" and enabling the spark. streaming. backpressure. enabled"="true" it uses max receiver capacity. so still issue exist." may you please elaborate a little more.

Comment: please share the details like what is your source of data and type, how many partitions per topic and how you created the Dstream.

Comment: @ Prudvi Sagar, Source of Data is Sensor which pushes messages to Kafka as Json message, right now we have per topics 5 partition, dstream is created by DirectAPI now not via create Streams

Comment: have you used "KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](streamingContext, kafkaParams, topics)" method to create the DStream.

Comment: Yes I am using DirectAPI now earlier I was using createStreams

Comment: I hope your issue has resolved now by using DirectAPI if not so please specify what you are facing exactly. I have updated my answer please check once.

Comment: @ Prudvi Sagar Thank you so much for your help on this. Definitely I am going to accept this as an answer. Just one more query :) I have 1 topic with 1 partition When I see Spark Streaming UI I can see only 1 executor is handling all the task rest of the executors are completely idle. Any help or pointer on this will be helpful to use cluster efficiently.

Comment: I have updated this in my answer. KafkaUtil.createStream(....) single Receiver will be run in an spark executor and if the topic is partioned, multiple receiver threads run for each partition. If you are usingKafkaUtil.KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](streamingContext, kafkaParams, topics), In this case instead of single receiver spark executors directly connect to the kafka partition leads and receive the data parallel(each kafka partition is one KafkaRDD partition).

Comment: refer the [link](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/03/30/improvements-to-kafka-integration-of-spark-streaming.html)

Comment: That means for 1 topic with 1 partition single machine will do the processing rest of the machine will be idle strange even task are not parallelized.